# How to import PG dump from digitalocean to local machine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, import, digital-ocean

I am new to rails. 
I want to take backup of pg database from digitalocean to my local machine. How I take dump of that and migrate to my local machine

Comment: Have you tried to find a subject? There is a billion tutorials in the internet.

Answer (score 2):

To use pg_dump,

First, for the target machine(remote machine with database you want to dump), two steps to make the machine receive pg_dump requests:

1.Add or edit the following line in your postgresql.conf :(in my experience, the location maybe /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf, replace 9.3 with your psql version. If nobody change the file before, you add the line below to the end of the file)

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

2.Add the following line as the first line of file 'pg_hba.conf'. (in my experience, the location like /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf)  It allows access to all databases for all users with an encrypted password:

```
# TYPE DATABASEUSER CIDR-ADDRESS  METHOD
host  all all all  md5
```

After those two steps, type in the terminal:

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql start
```

At last, in your local machine, you should figure out the target database's user(or owner) who can read it:

You can achieve this by ssh to connect that machine and  step into psql console

```
sudo su - postgres && psql
```

and type

```
\l
```

to see the db owner.

Finally you can use pg_dump in your local machine to dump the database.Like :

```
pg_dump -f dump_name -h host_ip -d database_name -U database_user -p 5432 -W
```

then input the user's password, and wait for the long time for dumping the db.

Hope you make it~

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create backup then download dump from digital ocean and the run these commands on console.
Download dump using SCP.

```
1-pg_dump dbname > outfile
2-pg_restore --verbose --clean --jobs=4 --disable-triggers --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U user_name -d database_name outfile.dump
```